# Kernel of an action

Tags: group-theory

$$G = \left\{ 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  a & b \\
  0 & 1  \\
  \end{pmatrix}
\text{with $a$ in $\{1, -1\}$ and $b$ in } \mathbb{Z}\right\}$$

G is a subgroup of the matrix group $GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$.

$\phi : G \rightarrow \{1,-1\} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is given by $ (
 \begin{smallmatrix}
  a & b \\
  0 & 1  \\
  \end{smallmatrix})
\rightarrow (a,\overline{b})$

Is the kernel of $\phi$ equal to $ \left\{ 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 \\
  0 & 1  \\
  \end{pmatrix}^n
\text{with $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ } \right\}$? Give a proof or a counterexample.

I'm totally stuck on this question. How would one go about answering this? I know the kernel of an action $G$ on $S$ is defined as $\{g \in G \vert g \cdot s = s \text{ for all $s$ in $S$}\}$, but I don't know how to go from there. For instance, what is $S$ in this case? Or is that even the way to go?

Comment: What is $\phi$? This is undefined.

Comment: Do you mean the stabiliser?

Comment: @ choco_addicted, added it. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to clarify the notation $\bar b =^{?} (b \mod 2)$. Also, hint: eigenvalue decomposition.

Comment: @AnotherTest, $\overline{b}$ is just an equivalence class in $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$. I don't see how eigenvalue decomposition is related to this question. Care to elaborate?

Comment: You write about the kernel of an action. But this question appears to be about the kernel of the homomorphism $\phi$, not the kernel of some action. The concepts "kernel of an action" and "kernel of a homomorphism", while related to each other, are not identical concepts.

Comment: @LeeMosher, in class we only covered the kernel of an action. So I assumed it was the same thing. Any thoughts on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: All I can say is, learn about the kernel of a group homomorphism. For example, that's how the answer of @JohnDouma is formulated.

Comment: @LeeMosher what is the difference between the kernel of an action $(G \times S \to S)$ and the kernel of the homomorphism corresponding to this action $(G \to S \times S)$?

Comment: The kernel of the action $G \times S \mapsto S$ is ***defined*** to be the kernel of the homomorphism $G \mapsto S \times S$ corresponding to that action.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes. The group $\{1,-1\}\times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ has $(1, \bar 0)$ as its identity.

The kernel of $\phi$ is therefore all matrices of the form $ \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2n \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$

But ${\begin{pmatrix}
       1 & 2 \\
       0 & 1
     \end{pmatrix}}^n=\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2n \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$ as can be seen by induction.

Answer (score 2):

The question is somewhat confusing since $\phi$ is not a group action. It is a group homomorphism, as such that is what this answer is about.

The unit element of $\{1, -1\}$ is $1$ (assuming multiplication as the group operation). That of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is $\bar 0$.
Hence the unit element of the direct product is $(1, \bar 0)$.

You ask when $\phi\left(\pmatrix{a & b \\ 0 & 1}\right) = (1, \bar 0)$.

This is clearly the case if and only if $a = 1$ and $b = 2n$ for some $n \in \mathbb Z$.

So the kernel consists of all matrices

$$\pmatrix{1 & 2n \\ 0 & 1}$$

What remains is to show that

$$\pmatrix{1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1}^n = \pmatrix{1 & 2n \\ 0 & 1}$$

You can use the eigenvalue decomposition of the matrix to show this, since (conveniently) it exists in $\mathbf{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$.